# FirstObject XML editor -- schema constrained?

Tags: xml, xsd

Does anyone know if the xml editor at http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm can be constrained by schema? It states that it can be DTD-constrained or by well-formed rules, but does not mention schemas. Before downloading the product, thought I'd check with you all. Thanks.
New Edit: It has MSXML validation so I will assume that it is schema constrained.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in an edit to my question, it has MSXML validation so I will assume that it is schema constrained.